# AttributeError: validation_data can't be accessed in Custom Callback

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I implemented a prediction model with a LSTM and wrote a custom callback in order to access some additional metrics on the reverse scaled input.

The Metrics class looks like this:

```py
class Metrics(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, scaler):
        self.scaler = scaler

    def on_train_begin(self, logs):
        self._data = []

    def on_epoch_end(self, batch, logs):
        val_data, val_target = self.validation_data[0], self.validation_data[1]

        # calculating and appending the metric here
        # self._data.append({metric})

        return

    def get_data(self):
        return self._data
```

I then use it like this:

```py
metrics = Metrics(scaler)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, 
                   return_sequences=True,
                   activation='tanh', 
                   input_shape=(dataset.X_train.shape[1], dataset.X_train.shape[2])))
# more layers and model.compile here

history = model.fit(dataset.X_train, 
                    dataset.y_train,  
                    epochs=EPOCHS,  
                    validation_data=(dataset.X_valid, dataset.y_valid), 
                    callbacks=[metrics])
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can add this way it works ```class Metrics(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, scaler, train_data, y_train, valid_data, y_val):```

Comment: @utks009 but then I would add the entire train/ validation dataset before the actual training of the model? because actually I only wanna access the validation data at the end of each epoch..

Comment: You can also use only validation data, in the callbacks ```class Metrics(keras.callbacks.Callback): def __init__(self, scaler, valid_data, y_val):``` and then use on_epoch_end.

Comment: You can also use `valid_data` from `keras.util.sequence`